# Writing a trail guide for mountain bike trails - advice on the process

Tags: formatting

I'm writing a trail guide about mountain bike trails in a little known Eastern European country.

I have many maps and trails but I would like some advice about which software to use to write it up, structure the book and take it onto formatting for ebook.

What are the essential elements of the text - info and writing style?

I've got Scrivener and Indesign but Scrivener seems to be better for books with not a lot of design layout and indesign is the opposite- good for design but not for the writing process.

Any advice welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are two different programs for two different tasks.

Scrivener is for writing your text. InDesign is for laying out the completed text after it's written and edited.

I have written fiction in InDesign, but I'm also a production artist and I spend so much time in InDesign that I'm very comfortable in it, so I don't mind using it as a word processor sometimes.